# Visual Studio 2022 is not refactoring properly

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring

VS keeps suggesting to fix naming violations. That would be not that bad if only suggested refactoring worked as expected. Which is not, in my case

[image]

[image]

[image]

for as you can see name has been fixed from 'getCountryCode' to 'GetCountryCode', but all references are now broken, which is quite annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `Ctrl + R + R` to change name of functions or variables